# How to dynamically create a new gameobject and add the gameobject in scene Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do you do.
I want to create a new gameobject and then add the gameobject in scene.

How do I do this?

My code is:

```
GameObject a = new GameObject();
GameObject aClone = Instantiate(a) as GameObject;
```

but doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 15):

The correct way:

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
```

You can specify the `position` and the `rotation` as well.

```
Vector3 position    = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
Quaternion rotation = new Quaternion(1, 1, 1, 1);
GameObject obj      = Instantiate(prefab, position, rotation) as GameObject;
```

Obviously use the `position` and `rotation` that you like by changing the parameters.

A [**prefab**](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) is simply:

```
public GameObject prefab;
```

Drag a `GameObject` into the script via the Editor.

Comment: Can I have a new GameObject without having a prefab?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate takes 3 arguments, the `gameObject`, the position and the rotation. This will put it in your scene depending on what you parse in as values.

```
Instantiate(a, Vector3 (x, y, z), Quaternion.identity);
```